# How to measure app execution power consumption in android?

Tags: android, consumption

I'm developing android app using OpenCL for CPU-GPU parallel computing. I want to measure CPU-GPU each power consumption or total power consumption in app execution. But I can't find proper measurement method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Developer site provides you with all you need :

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

You can :

1.Monitor the Battery Level and Charging State

2.Determine and Monitor the Docking State and Type

Answer (score 2):

I have used [ODROID-XU](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G137510300620) to measure energy consumption in CPU and GPU.
They provide power sensors for the 2 CPUs, GPU, and memory.

I have made a few scripts for collecting and analysing such data. Available here:
https://github.com/luiscruz/greenbenchmark

This is a good approach if you need reliable measurements.
On the contrary, software-based approaches only provide an estimation which might not be accurate.